# Changing name of outputlayer dynamically in QGIS Processing script?

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a processing script to load txt-data from a magnetometer and convert them into a vectorlayer (to make a raster in a second step). I want the name of output layer to be changed into something related to the input filename. The initAlgorithm function looks like this:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    # We add the input File Parameter.
    self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterFile(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr('Magnetometer File'),
        0,
        'txt'
       )
    )
    # and the output vector layer
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
        self.OUTPUT,
        self.tr('Magnetometer points'),
        type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint))
```

The new output layer is named **Magnetometer points**, but should be better something like **Magnetometer points File1**

How and where can I achieve this - I suppose in the processAlgorithm function?